# iterating through each line and each character in a file

Tags: bash, unix

i'm trying to get a file name, and a character index, and to print me the characters with that index from each line (and do it for each character index the user enters if such character exists).
This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read file_name
while read x
do
    if [ -f $file_name ]
    then
            while read string
            do
                    counter=0
                    while read -n char
                    do
                            if [ $counter -eq $x ]
                            then
                                    echo $char
                            fi
                            counter=$[$counter+1]
                    done < $(echo -n "$string")
            done < $file_name
    fi
done
```

But, it says an error:

```
line 20: abcdefgh: No such file or directory
```

line 20 is the last `done`, so it doesn't help me figure out where is the error.

So what's wrong in my code and how do I fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think "cut" might fit the bill:

```
read file_name
if [ -f $file_name ]
then
    while read -n char
    do
        cut -c $char $file_name
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be problematic:

```
done < $(echo -n "$string")
```

Replace that with:

```
done < <(echo -n "$string")
```

Comment: Care to explain? and now it says a different error: `line 10: read: char: invalid number`

Comment: Yes that is because of `read -n` which expects a number. Also that syntax is process substitution, read more about it here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I don't get what `< <(echo -n "$string")` is about, the `< <(` part especially.

Comment: `<` is for indirection and `<(echo -n "$string")` is syntax for process substitution. Please check the link I have provided for more examples on it.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
                counter=0
                while read -n char
                do
                        if [ $counter -eq $x ]
                        then
                                echo $char
                        fi
                        counter=$[$counter+1]
                done < $(echo -n "$string")
```

with

```
if [ $x -lt ${#string} ]
then
    echo ${line:$x:1}
fi
```

It does the same, but allows to avoid such errors.

Another approach is using `cut`

```
cut -b $(($x+1)) $file_name  | grep -v "^$"
```

It can replace two inner loops